# IE9 createElement and setting innerHTML dropping tags on a set operation?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

Not sure if I am missing something obvious, as this is the first time I've tried to do much with raw DOM apis (as opposed to via jQuery, or such).

Consider the following code, where I manually create a TBODY with document.createElement and then set it's innerHTML.

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var row = "<tr><td><span>col1</span></td><td>col2</td></tr>";
    var render = function(){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        tbody.innerHTML = row;
        table.appendChild(tbody);

        console.log(tbody.innerHTML);
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        render();
    });
</script>
```

In Chrome and FF, this works as I thought it would - giving me a table, etc.  However, in IE9, it seems the first HTML tags in the innerHTML are being dropped.  i.e., instead of

```
<TR><TD><SPAN>col1</SPAN></TD><TD>col2</TD></TR>
```

I get

```
<SPAN>col1</SPAN></TD><TD>col2</TD></TR>
```

A JSFiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/pAJwu/

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE up to version 9 doesn't support setting `innerHTML` on some elements. [Here's why](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html); the link also includes possible workaround.

Comment: Wow... that blog post is 5+ years old, and he mentions the source of this problem being from 10 years prior to that.  Amazing that this problem continues to exist today.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Finally, after many years with this issue, is being supported on IE10